# Unable to find image 'xyz' locally

Tags: docker

I try to build a docker image that contains a cross build environment to build binaries for Xilinx Petalinux on a M1 MacBook using Docker Desktop version 4.16.2. It looks like the docker build works:

```
% docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 --build-arg PETA_RUN_FILE=petalinux-v2021.2-final-installer.run -t petalinux_2021_2 .
[+] Building 1.8s (17/17) FINISHED                                                                                               
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.15kB                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                             1.7s
 => [copy_installer 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:a3765b4d74747b5e9bdd03205b3fbc4fa19a02781c185f97f24c8f  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:a3765b4d74747b5e9bdd03205b3fbc4fa19a02781c185f97f24c8f4f84ed7bbf       0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 552B                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [copy_installer 2/3] RUN chmod a+rx /${PETA_RUN_FILE_NAME} &&   mkdir -p /opt/Xilinx &&   chmod 777 /tmp /opt/X  0.0s
 => CACHED [copy_installer 3/3] COPY petalinux-v2021.2-final-installer.run /                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  1/10] RUN apt-get update &&  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -q   build-essential    0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  2/10] RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 &&  apt-get update &&        DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive ap  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  3/10] RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && update-locale                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  4/10] RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' vivado &&   usermod -aG sudo vivado &&   echo "vivad  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  5/10] RUN cd /tmp &&   sudo -u vivado /petalinux-v2021.2-final-installer.run --skip_license --dir /op  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  6/10] RUN echo "dash dash/sh boolean false" | debconf-set-selections                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  7/10] RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure dash                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  8/10] RUN mkdir /home/vivado/project                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  9/10] WORKDIR /home/vivado/project                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 10/10] RUN echo "source /opt/Xilinx/petalinux/settings.sh" >> /home/vivado/.bashrc                      0.0s
```

When I repeat that multiple times, I get the message, that the steps are cached. However, I also receive this warning:

```
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
```

Using the image from cache, would be totally ok for me. But, if I want to run the image, I receive the error message, that there is no such image:

```
% docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --rm -ti petalinux_2021_2 bash
Unable to find image 'petalinux_2021_2:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for petalinux_2021_2, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

How can I access the resulting image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default buildx doesn't save image locally (I think they're counting on push arg).
But if you don't want to push the image to the registry, just add `--output type=docker` to your command and you should see it normally by `docker images` command.